# How do I prove that if $x \in V_\alpha$, then $\bigcup x \in V_{\alpha + 1}$, where $V_{\alpha+1} = P(V_\alpha)$ and $V$ is the von Neumann Universe?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

This is a problem that was on a final I took in my Set Theory class and I just couldn’t figure it out.  The test is over and I already got the problem wrong, I’m just trying to go back and figure it out and make sure I understand the material before moving on to the next course.

I have a photo of an attempted solution but have less than 10 reputation.

The upshot is that I can’t figure out how to get $\bigcup x \in P(V_\alpha)$.  I’ve tried everything I can think of for hours with no luck.  I’ve done everything that I’m ever gonna do at this point, still no luck.

The best I’ve got is that $x\in V_{\alpha+1}$ since $V_{\alpha}$ is a subset of $V_{\alpha+1}$. But this leaves no clear path into how the union of $x$ is in the power set of $V_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Please use the preview to ensure your question is in its final form before posting it. It is hard to help when your question is edited every minute.

Comment: I had lots of typos in the math script.  It’s done now.

Comment: Again, please use the preview feature to ensure there are no errors _before_ you post the question.

Comment: Fine.  So what, because if that no help?

Comment: I wouldn't phrase it so roughly, but yes. We don't want to read the rough draft of your question, any more than you want to read the rough drafts of our answers. The preview feature makes it easy to refine your question, so when you don't it can seem like you don't care about our time.

Comment: Well, the point is well taken and I see the merit, but the question is now very much in it’s final form.  Though I must say, I didn’t expect a mini temper-tantrum.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \in V_{\alpha}$. Recall that
$$
\bigcup x = \{ z \mid \exists y \in x \colon z \in y\} = \bigcup_{y \in x} y.
$$
For any $y \in x$ we have, because $V_{\alpha}$ is transitive, that $y \subseteq V_{\alpha}$. Hence $\bigcup x = \bigcup_{y \in x} y \subseteq V_{\alpha}$ and thus $\bigcup x \in \mathcal P(V_{\alpha}) = V_{\alpha + 1}$.

---

If you already know that $V_{\alpha} = \{x \mid \mathrm{rank}_{\in}(x) < \alpha\}$, there is an even easier argument: Every element $z \in \bigcup x$ has rank $\mathrm{rank}_{\in}(z) < \mathrm{rank}_{\in}(x) < \alpha$. Since
$$
\mathrm{rank}_{\in}(\bigcup x) = \sup \{ \mathrm{rank}_{\in}(z)+1 \mid z \in \bigcup x \},
$$
we have $\mathrm{rank}_{\in}(\bigcup x) \le \mathrm{rank}_{\in}(x) < \alpha$ and hence $\bigcup x \in V_{\alpha} \subseteq V_{\alpha+1}$. (And this result is optimal since it is possible that $\bigcup x = x$, e.g. when $x$ is a limit ordinal.)

Answer (score 1):

From the def'n $V_a=\cup_{b\in a}V_b$ if $a=\cup a,$ and $V_{a+1}=P(V_a)$ we obtain by transfinite induction on $a$ that $V_a$ is a transitive set: $\forall x\in V_a\;(x\subset V_a).$

Let $x\in V_a.$  Then for all $y $ we have $$y\in x\in V_a\implies y \in x\subset V_a\implies y\in V_a\implies y\subset V_a.$$   So $\cup x=\cup \{y:y\in x\}$ is a union of subsets of $V_a,$ so $\cup x\in P(V_a)=V_{a+1}.$